# Turn off a monitor through remote login

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to know how to turn off a monitor through remote login in linux. And also how to turn it on. Pleas help....

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ssh -X user@host
xset dpms force off
xset dpms force on
```

Comment: Not working... It gives me an error 'xset:  unable to open display "'...

Comment: You might need to tell xset what X-display to talk to:  export DISPLAY=:0

Comment: how do i do that

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ssh -X <user>
```

check if this exists,

```
cat /proc/acpi/info
```

Do the following,

> xset q

If you get the DPMS error, do the following. Otherwise Skip.

> xset +dpms

If this file exists, then you can turn of your monitor from your terminal. You need to have ACPI enable in your kernel to do so, and the presence of this file ensures that it is.

```
xset dpms force off
```

^Use this command after that.

you can use this tutorial to see how to enable ACPI. Although it is usually set enabled by default in kernel.

http://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-list/2004-January/msg02841.html

Comment: when i type xset -q in the terminal i get the message as  Server does not have the DPMS Extension

Comment: I have edited the answer to fix the error you are getting. Hopefully it should work now.

Comment: Anyways I think `xset dpms force off` will turn off the local monitor not the remote one (and I don't know how to turn the remote monitor off).

Answer (score 1):

When you login on X11 via remote, it create a fake Display called localhost:11.0(the name can change).

```
ssh remote
echo $DISPLAY 
localocalhost:11.0
```

Every X application you run (xterm,xeyes,xset,xrandr,etc) will display the output tunneled via ssh(so encrypted) on the real display on local machine.
So if you use command like this

```
xset dpms force off
```

or

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --off
```

they will affect your local machine and not the remote.
If you try ssh without X11 forwarding, X11 don't allow for security reason commands(x11 is in clear, not encrypted).
The solution is to use the flag -display
So if you want to turn off display from remote, first see the output of xset(you can also try xrandr, but in my pc xset works better).

```
ssh -Y -q remote xset -display :0.0 -q|grep -i monitor\ is
  Monitor is On
```

Monitor is turned on, now we turn off

```
ssh -q -Y remote xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

Now we check again, must report off

```
ssh -Y -q remote xset -display :0.0 -q|grep -i monitor\ is
  Monitor is Off
```

Comment: Trying this on my openSUSE system doesn't turn off the monitor, but instead results in the following output:
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxset:  unable to open display ":0.0"

Comment: Check if X11Forward is enable on ssh server side

Comment: Yes, X11Forward is enabled server-side.

Comment: Try if X11 forward work: open ssh -Y remote , and open a graphical app(xeyes, xcalc, etc) if doesn't work try with ssh -X instead of ssh -Y, if even this doesn't work I don't know.